# How to stop executing a bash script if upon the next check the IP address hasn't been changed?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I tried my best with the Title, but it's better if I give you a simple example of what needs to be done in a bash script.

```
curl ident.me
#this one checks my current public IP address

curl [a post request]
#sending a curl post request

curl ident.me
#again, it checks my current public IP address

curl [a different post request]
#it will send the curl post request ONLY if the IP address we got with the previous curl request is DIFFERENT than the one we got when we previously used the same command to check for the current IP address. If it's not different, it should stop/pause the script.
```

Any ideas ? Google is of no help due to the difficulty of precisely technically phrasing the question.

Comment: Split the task into pieces to make it easier to digest. You already know a command to get the public IP address. You need some way to store it from the command output (to a variable). Then you need to do it again, and compare to the stored value (perhaps by storing the new value in another variable).

Answer (score 1):

I would store the result of each curl in a variable and then compare if the result of each curl matches each other in an if statement.

```
a=$(curl ident.me)
curl [a post request]
b=$(curl ident.me)

if [ "$a" != "$b" ]
then
  echo "do not match" && ...
else 
  exit
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

A function would make it easier:

```
die() { printf>&2 '%s\n' "$@"; exit 1; }

ip= prev_ip=
retrieve_public_ip() {
  ip=$(curl --no-progress-meter https://ident.me) && [ -n "$ip" ] ||
    die "Can't determine my public IP address"

  [ "$ip" != "$prev_ip" ] ||
    die "My public IP address has not changed. Aborting"

  prev_ip=$ip
}

retrieve_public_ip
curl [a post request]

retrieve_public_ip
curl [a different post request]

# and so on.
```